# How can I change the colour behind the UITableViewCell while editing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a standard UITableViewCell with a backgroundColor property set differently to the tableView backgroundColor. As you can see in the image, the part of the cell on the overshoot when editing, is not coloured (white).

[image: UITableViewCell editing overshoot]

I've tried setting the

```
• cell.backgroundColor
• cell.contentView.backgroundColor
• cell.backgroundView with a UIView() set with a backgroundColor
```

Nothing seems to work :( The tableView cannot be that colour due to alternating colour cells (white, offWhite, etc.)

Edit: The tableView must remain white due to it potentially not being very full and matching the UI.

Comment: one option would be to set the entire table view's background color to whatever you want it to be while you are editing and cover that by setting each cell's contentView background color property to white/offWhite and then setting it to clear when they are editing

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil that link isn't related to iOS and isn't in Swift or even Objective-C I'm afraid